# Does India require its citizens to report income wherever they reside and earn (abroad)?

Tags: income-tax, india, non-resident, working-abroad

I have read that:
"The U.S. requires its citizens to file tax returns reporting their earnings wherever they reside. However, there are some measures designed to reduce the international double taxation that results from this requirement" . Does the same hold true for Indian government too? i.e. 
Does India require its citizens to report income wherever they reside and earn..?

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit the question and ask specifics. There are lots of variations and it will not be possible to answer every aspect of the taxation in a single question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working from India; the services are consumed outside India, then you are required to pay tax in India. So essentially if you take-up a contract for some software firm and get paid in USD, then you are liable to pay tax in India on the earning.

There are whole bunch of exceptions if you render your services outside India, For example you travel to a country and render the service for which you get paid. In most of these cases its not taxable in India.